# What is the difference between hbase and hive? (Hadoop)

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, bigdata, nosql

From my understanding, Hbase is the Hadoop database and Hive is the data warehouse.

Hive allows to create tables and store data in it, you can also map your existing HBase tables to Hive and operate on them.

why we should use hbase if hive do all that? can we use hive by itself? 
I'm confused :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in simple terms, with hive you can fire SQL like queries (with some exceptions) on your table/s and is used in batch operation. While with hbase, you can do real time querying and is based on key value pair.

"why we should use hbase if hive do all that? can we use hive by itself" Because Hive doesn't supports updating your data set. So if you have large analytical processing application use Hive and if you have real time get/set/update request processing, use Hbase.

Comment: So from what you said I can understand that hive have a local database and when I do updates on it this can't affect the NoSql database which is Hbase, I agree with this. But in my case I just need to use Hive because it's much easier to use  HiveQL than using the put/get/scan operations provides by Hbase.And I think that Hbase don't have a jdbc driver that allows to connect my eclipse app to create databases and tables...

Comment: No both maintains data and flavor and you can't directly change the data stored by hbase using hive. For connecting to hbase you could see [this](https://github.com/forcedotcom/phoenix)
Phoenix: A SQL skin over HBase 'We put the SQL back in NoSQL' Phoenix is a SQL skin over HBase, delivered as a client-embedded JDBC driver, powering the HBase use cases at Salesforce.com. Phoenix targets low-latency queries (milliseconds), as opposed to batch operation via map/reduce. To see what's supported, go to our language reference guide, read more on our wiki, and download it.

Comment: I can use  the "HBaseStorageHandler" to register HBase tables with the Hive metastore by creating external tables no?

Comment: So I can create tables using hive in hbase :) 
Thank you for your help